# SQL to select Top/Highest count when using Group By

Tags: sql, count, group-by

Can anyone help me with SQL that will return highest count for App_ID. I'm running this SQL which returns following data set.

```
SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, count(*) as cnt 
FROM APP_ACCT_VIEW
GROUP BY COMP_ID, APP_ID

COMP_ID APP_ID                    CNT
cpo1000c    AT                    999
cpo1kact    AT                    895
cpo1kact    CPOPYMTS_Administrative    1020
cpo1000c    CPOPYMTS_HighValue           1900
cpo1kact    CPOPYMTS_HighValue           1020
cpo1000c    CPOPYMTS_Internal            1999
cpo1kact    CPOPYMTS_Internal            1020
cpo1kact    IRCDR                     1020
cpo1000c    IRCDR                     50
```

But I need SQL to return the top/highest cnt for each APP_ID and need output to look like this.

```
COMP_ID APP_ID                    CNT
cpo1000c    AT                    999
cpo1kact    CPOPYMTS_Administrative    1020
cpo1000c    CPOPYMTS_HighValue           1900
cpo1000c    CPOPYMTS_Internal            1999
cpo1kact    IRCDR                     1020
```

Thanks
Dipen

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most databases, you can use the `row_number()` function to do this:

```
select comp_id, app_id, cnt
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by app_id order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from (SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, count(*) as cnt
            FROM APP_ACCT_VIEW
            GROUP BY COMP_ID, APP_ID
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

If this is not available, you have to do the calculation of seqnum some other way, such as a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL-Server 2005 or higher you can use a CTE with the `ROW_Number` or `DENSE_RANK` function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, 
       CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY APP_ID, COMP_ID) ,
       RN  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY APP_ID ORDER BY CNT DESC) 
    FROM APP_ACCT_VIEW
)
SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, CNT
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

If you use `DENSE_RANK` instead you would get multiple records per `APP_ID` if they have the same (highest) `CNT` unlike `ROW_NUMBER` which always returns one result per group.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay... I'm running SQL on Aginity Netezza Workbench. I got the following message when I ran the SQL.

/* ERROR [42S22] ERROR:  Attribute 'CNT' not found */
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, 
       CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY APP_ID),
       RN  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY APP_ID ORDER BY CNT DESC) 
    FROM CPODWH_NCT1.CPODWH_ADM.APP_ACCT_VIEW
)
SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, CNT
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;

Comment: Not to be picky, Tim, but you are a popular guy.  You answered 2-3 minutes after me, have incorrect logic (should be `partition by comp_id` for `rn` and `partition by app_id, comp_id` for cnt) and still got three upvotes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: OP wants the highest count for each `APP_ID`. Please read again the question.

Comment: @user2062662: I must admit that i have no experiences with `Aginity Natezza Workbench`, i don't know if it supports partition functions at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . The example groups by app_id and comp_id to generate the counts.  I read the statement as "the highest count for App_Id for each Comp_id" in that context.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: OP's first query (and the result) is what he has tried but not the desired result. The desired result does not contain duplicate `COMP_ID` and only the highest `CNT` for each `APP_ID`, so exactly what he wants(_"I need SQL to return the top/highest cnt for each APP_ID"_).

Comment: @TimSchmelter . . . The desired result is a subset of the first query.  I don't see how you can get the result *without* summarizing by `comp_id` and `app_id`.  Your query, as written now, should presumably return an error because `cnt` isn't defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: ok, you've made your point! Meanwhile i've overlooked that `CNT` is an aggrgated column. (+1 for you)

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY APP_ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.APP_ACCT_VIEW
  GROUP BY COMP_ID, APP_ID
  )
  SELECT COMP_ID, APP_ID, cnt
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ce8d/1/0)